# Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 in Angular2/Ionic2

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2

I have linked my app into NodeJS server, after the get request goes(sucsses) I get an error on the app `Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL: null`.

This is the lastest branch of the app:
https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/tree/DB-LINKED

And this is the NodeJS server: 
https://github.com/eshk12/parabiNodeJS

I am talking about the function `CreateMedicine()` inside `/Services/NetworkServices.ts`.

The function `CreateMedicine()` goes to `http://localhost:3000/Medicines/add/` with its `GET` parameters and insert them to the database.
but unknown error appear.

Hope you guys may help me fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: its most likely a cors issue have you done this:  [enable cors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that happens when the OPTIONS call fails. Most likely due to the service being unavailable.

> OPTIONS http://localhost/api/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED